# How to call ids from different tables

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a sqlite databse in that I have 3 tables called `Cases`, `Questions` and `options`.

Table1 cases structure is

> id      description.

table2 Question is

> id      description

table3 options structure is

> question_id    choices

Now how can I call cases id to question id and question id to options question_id. It should display in a single view.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: How are cases and questions related? Do questions belong to a case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to do some more reading up on basic SQL opertations, but I THINK what you are after is:

```
SELECT Cases.id AS Cases_Id, Cases.description as Cases_Desc,
    Questions.id AS Questions_Id, Questions.description as Questions_Desc,
    choices
FROM Cases 
INNER JOIN Questions ON Cases.id = Questions.id
INNER JOIN Options ON Options.Questions.id = Options.question_id
```